# Shopify has the inbox chat feature. Is it possible to open this chat box when the user clicks a button that I have created?

Tags: shopify

I have a contact us section on my shopify website. I want the shopify chatbox to open when user clicks on this. However, since the shopify inbox is an app, is it possible to do so. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add MutationObserver in custom js and dispatch 'click' event on a button. But after first virtual click iframe swaps to another, so you need to listen it too.
Something like this:

```js
function clickChat() {
  const event = new MouseEvent('click', {
    view: window,
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });

  const b = document.querySelector("[href='#live-chat']");
  if (b) {
      b.addEventListener('click', function() {
        const check = document.getElementById('ShopifyChat');
        const cb = document.getElementById('dummy-chat-button-iframe');
        if (check) {
          check.contentWindow.document.querySelector('[aria-controls="chat-ui"]').dispatchEvent(event);
        } else if (cb) {
          cb.contentWindow.document.querySelector('.chat-toggle').dispatchEvent(event);
        }
      })
    }
  }

var observeDOM = (function(){
  var MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

  return function( obj, callback ){
    if( !obj || obj.nodeType !== 1 ) return; 

    if( MutationObserver ){
      var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(callback)

      mutationObserver.observe( obj, { childList:true, subtree:true })
      return mutationObserver
    }
    else if( window.addEventListener ){
      obj.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', callback, false)
    }
  }
})()

listElm = document.querySelector('body');

observeDOM( listElm, function(m){ 
  var addedNodes = [], removedNodes = [];

  m.forEach(record => record.addedNodes.length & addedNodes.push(...record.addedNodes))

  if (addedNodes[0] !== undefined) {
    let id = addedNodes[0].id;
    if (id === 'dummy-chat-button-iframe' || id === 'shopify-chat') {
      clickChat();
    }
  }
});
```